# Get data that varies by the hour

Tags: python, azure-functions, interpreter

I am trying to retrieve the information of a web page XE.com for the conversion of the Euro to the Colombian Peso in an azure function that must run 3 times a today, tomorrow afternoon and night, and I managed to do it with Pandas, but this only works the first time, since the value remains in the interpreter  memory and each record shows the same change, I can not restart it or restore it, anyone knows how I can do it,?

pandas implementation:-

```py
import pandas as pd

url_EUR_COP = 'https://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=1&From=EUR&To=COP'
lst_url_EUR_COP = pd.read_html(url_EUR_COP)
df_trm_EUR_COP = pd.DataFrame(lst_url_EUR_COP[0])
```

Additional options:

```py
exit()
quit()
```

Additional options above do not work and generate error at the end of the function

In this case there is no small variance between the 6 minutes in my file; but there is on the page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a caching issue with pandas while getting the data from web page. You may be receiving the same value because the data is being saved in memory and reused for successive calls, which may prevent it from being updated.

***In your Function init.py use requests library like below:-***

**`My init.py`**

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
import azure.functions as func
import json

def fetch_eur_to_cop_conversion():
    url_EUR_COP = 'https://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=1&From=EUR&To=COP'
    response = requests.get(url_EUR_COP)
    lst_url_EUR_COP = pd.read_html(response.text)
    df_trm_EUR_COP = pd.DataFrame(lst_url_EUR_COP[0])
    return df_trm_EUR_COP.to_dict()

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    conversion_data = fetch_eur_to_cop_conversion()
    response = {
        "conversion_data": conversion_data
    }
    return func.HttpResponse(
        json.dumps(response),
        status_code=200,
        mimetype="application/json"
    )
```

**Output:-
Local:-**

[image]

[image]

I deployed the same code in Azure Function app and got successful results:-

[image]

Comment: Hii @SiddheshDesai, I appreciate the correction and answer, but you're only displaying the first result in your case.
In your correction you only put one execution per day, but I need three per day, and the error is that having multiple executions, always keeps the last value, as in the screenshot always the value Euro - COP is 4,403.75.

Comment: Just for information I use a TriggerTime

Comment: You can make use of web_scraper library beautiful soup and try the logic here - import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_EUR_COP = 'https://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=1&From=EUR&To=COP'
response = requests.get(url_EUR_COP)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
conversion_rate = soup.find('span', {'class': 'converterresult-toAmount'}).text
print(conversion_rate)